# Weird antlr grammar rule

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, antlr3

I have found an old file that define antlr grammar rules like that:

```
rule_name[ ParamType *param ] > [ReturnType *retval]:
  <<
    $retval                    = NULL;
    OtherType1  *new_var1      = NULL;
    OtherType2    *new_var2    = NULL;
  >>
  subrule1[ param ] > [ $retval ]
| subrule2 > [new_var2] 
  <<
    if( new_var2 == SOMETHING ){
      $retval = something_related_to_new_var2;
    }
    else{
      $retval = new_var2;
    }
  >>
  { 
    somethingelse > [new_var_1]
    <<
      /* Do something with new_var_1 */
      $retval = new_var_1;
    >>
  }
;
```

I'm not an Antlr expert and It's the first time that i see this kind of semantic for a rule definition.
Does anybody know where I can find documentation/informations about this?
Even a keyword for a google search is welcome.

Edit:
It should be ANTLR Version 1.33MR33.

Comment: Are you sure this is actually an ANTLR grammar? I don't remember anymore what the syntax was with early ANTLR versions, but if you replace << and >> with curly braces (describing an action) it comes close to what ANTLR 3 uses. The var init at the top is strange however, because now you have define that before the rule colon. And also the param decl looks unfamiliar.

Comment: Yes. It should be ANTLR Version 1.33MR33.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found! Here is the guide:

http://www.antlr2.org/book/pcctsbk.pdf

I quote the interesting part of the pdf that answer to my question.

1) Page 47:

```
poly > [float r]
: <<float f;>>
term>[$r] ( "\+" term>[f] <<$r += f;>> )*
;
```

Rule poly is defined to have a return value called $r via the "> [float r]" notation; this is similar to the output redirection character of UNIX shells. Setting the value of $r sets the return value of poly. he first action after the ":" is an init-action (because it is the first action of a rule or subrule). The init-action defines a local variable called f that will be used in the (...)* loop to hold the return value of the term.

2) Page 85:

A rule looks like:

```
rule : alternative1
| alternative2
...
| alternativen
;
```

where each alternative production is composed of a list of elements that can be references to rules, references to tokens, actions, predicates, and subrules. Argument and return value definitions looks like the following where there are n arguments and m return values:

```
rule[arg1,...,argn] > [retval1,...,retvalm] : ... ;
```

The syntax for using a rule mirrors its definition:

```
a : ... rule[arg1,...,argn] > [v1,...,vm] ...
;
```

Here, the various vi receive the return values from the rule rule, each vi must be an l-value.

3) Page 87:

Actions are of the form <<...>> and contain user-supplied C or C++ code that must be executed during the parse.